# I need to FILTER in SWICTH Function in DAX ,Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, switch-statement, dax, daxstudio

Can someone help me, I don't know how to I apply the filter in this scenario.

`Dental1 = IF ('CME 20-22'[Product Class]="Dental Indemnity",`
`SWITCH(TRUE(),`
`'CME 20-22'[Basis]="Dental specialist in training",1,`
`'CME 20-22'[Basis]="Employer indemnified only",1,`
`'CME 20-22'[Basis]="New graduate",1,`
`'CME 20-22'[Basis]="Non-practising",1,`
`'CME 20-22'[Basis]="Gratuitous services only",1,0),0)`

I want also  to apply the following filters into the Switch function:

`'CME 20-22'[Category]= "Dental hygienist/therapist"`
`'CME 20-22'[Category]="Dental prosthetist"`
`'CME 20-22'[Category]="Dental therapist"`
`'CME 20-22'[Category]="Oral health therapist"`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsFSX.png)

Comment: Where do you run into the problem here?

Comment: Hi!, I just want to add the Filters, Category, into the switch statement, but I do not sure how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by filters?  Do you want to filter the results, apply switch function only to filtered dataset, or use those as another factor in switch statement?  You cannot directly filter the switch, whatever that means. 
Providing sample data and expected results would help significantly.

Comment: I will like to add filters to the Switch function. it that possible? , I am training to filter text values, in order to do switch statements and get a binary value(0 or 1), to then count the # of those specific values.

Comment: So you want to apply the value that comes from the switch only to the rows theat are meet the condition provided by the filter? Is that a calculated column?

Comment: I think that I got it!
Dental1 = if(
'CME 20-22'[Category] in {"Dentist","Endodontics","Forensic odontology","Oral and maxillofacial surgery","Oral medicine","Orthodontics","Paediatric dentistry","Periodontics","Prosthodontics","Special needs dentistry" }
&& 'CME 20-22'[Product Class]="Dental Indemnity",

SWITCH(TRUE(),

'CME 20-22'[Basis]="Dental specialist in training",1,
'CME 20-22'[Basis]="Employer indemnified only",1,
'CME 20-22'[Basis]="Gratuitous services only",1,
'CME 20-22'[Basis]="New graduate",1,
'CME 20-22'[Basis]="Non-practising",1,

0),
0)

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking about :) Good job! Btw. next time, try to better specify your question :)